# How To Create a React side bar with Submenu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react sidebar component with Submenu functionality from scratch and I came across a certain error, which I would like to be debugged.

Here are my codes below.

accordiondata.js

```
const accordionData = [
    {

    title: 'Our Office',
    subTitle:[

        {
            name:'Meet the Team',
            url:'/meet-the-team',
        },
        
        {
            name:'Why choose us',
            url:'/why-choose-us',
        },

        {
            name:'Blog ',
            url:'/blog',
        },
        
    ]

    },

    {

        title: 'Patient Info',
        subTitle:[

            {
                name:'Common Problems',
                url:'/common-problems',
            },

            {
                name:'First Visit',
                url:'/first-visit',
            },

            {
                name:'Financial and Ins',
                url:'/financial-and-ins',
            },


            {
                name:'FAQ',
                url:'/faq',
            },
                
        

        ]

    },

    {

        title: 'Treatments',
        subTitle:[

            {
                name:'Types of Braces',
                url:'/type-of-braces'
            },

            {
                name:'Orthodontics',
                url:'/orthodontics',
    
            },  
            
        ]

    },

    {

        title: 'Invisalign',
        subTitle:[
            {
                name:'Invisalign for Adults',
                url:'/invisalign-for-adults'
            },

            {
                name:'Invisalign for Kids',
                url:'/invisalign-for-kids'
            },

            {
                name:'Invisalign for Teens',
                url:'/invisalign-for-teens'
            },

            
            {
                name:'Cost of Invisalign',
                url:'/cost-of-invisalign'
            },

        ]

    },

    {

        title: 'Contact Us',
        subTitle:[

            {
                name:'Emergency Care',
                url:'/emergency-care',
            },

            {
                name:'Request an Appt',
                url:'/request-an-appt',
            },

            {
                name:'Park Cities Office',
                url:'/park-cities-office',
            },

            {
                name:'Lakewood Office',
                url:'/lakewood-office',
            },

            {
                name:'Preston Hollow Office',
                url:'/preston-hollow-office',
            },
            
        ]

    },


]


export default accordionData
```

and in my navbar.js file Here is what I have in there.

```
import  * as React  from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
import {Link} from "gatsby"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

import accordionData from "./accordiondata"


import { motion } from "framer-motion"


const Navbar  = () =>{

    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
            datoCmsGlobalContent {
                facebookLink
                linkedinLink
                instagramLink
                pinterestLink
                youtubeLink
                mainSiteLogo {
                    gatsbyImageData
                    alt
                }
                apptRequestCopy
                apptRequestLink
                telephoneNumber
                telephoneLink
            }
        }
    `)



    const [dropdown, setdropdown] = useState(false)

    const [subNav, setsubNav] = useState(false);

    const toggle = index =>{

        if (subNav === index){

            return setsubNav(null)
        }

        setsubNav(index)
    }

    const openDropdown  = () =>{

        setdropdown(true)

    }

    const closeDropdown  = () =>{

        setdropdown(false)

    }



    return(
        <>
        {/* The top navigational bar to show on mobile starts */}
        <div className="flex justify-center py-2 md:hidden ">
            <Link to="/">
                <GatsbyImage
                    image={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.mainSiteLogo.gatsbyImageData}
                    className="h-auto w-auto object-cover object-center"
                    alt="{data.datoCmsGlobalContent.mainSiteLogo.alt}"
                />
            </Link>
        </div>
        {/* The top navigational bar to show on mobile Ends */}

        {/* The navigational bar starts */}
        <nav className="relative flex justify-between py-2 px-6 bg-white text-gray-800 shadow-sm items-center tracking-wider sticky top-0 z-50">

            {/* The Navbar first flex section Starts*/}
            <div className="flex justify-between space-x-8 items-center">

                <button onClick={openDropdown} className="bg-ragan-purple flex p-3 rounded-md overflow-hidden space-x-4 items-center focus:outline-none">
                    <svg className="w-6 h-6 text-white" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                    </svg>
                    <span className="tracking-wider font-body text-white">MENU</span>
                </button>

                <Link to={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.apptRequestLink} >
                    <button className="bg-ragan-orange text-white  p-3 tracking-wider font-body rounded-md focus:outline-none hidden xl:block">
                        {data.datoCmsGlobalContent.apptRequestCopy}
                    </button>
                </Link>

            </div>
            {/* The Navbar First section Ends */}

            {/* The Navbar Second section Starts */}
            <div className="hidden lg:block">
                <Link to="/">
                    <GatsbyImage
                        image={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.mainSiteLogo.gatsbyImageData}
                        className="h-auto w-auto object-cover object-center"
                        alt="{data.datoCmsGlobalContent.mainSiteLogo.alt}"
                    />
                </Link>
            </div>
            {/* The Navbar Second section Ends */}

            {/* The Navbar first flex section Starts*/}
            <div className="flex justify-between space-x-8 items-center">

                <div>

                <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.telephoneLink}>
                <button className="bg-ragan-blue text-white py-3 px-3 tracking-wider font-body rounded-md focus:outline-none hidden xl:block">
                {data.datoCmsGlobalContent.telephoneNumber}
                </button>
                </a>

                </div>


                <div className="flex justify-between space-x-2 items-center">

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.facebookLink}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-facebook h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <path d="M7 10v4h3v7h4v-7h3l1 -4h-4v-2a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h3v-4h-3a5 5 0 0 0 -5 5v2h-3" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.linkedinLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-linkedin h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-green lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="2" />
                <line x1="8" y1="11" x2="8" y2="16" />
                <line x1="8" y1="8" x2="8" y2="8.01" />
                <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M16 16v-3a2 2 0 0 0 -4 0" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.instagramLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-instagram h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="4" />
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3" />
            <line x1="16.5" y1="7.5" x2="16.5" y2="7.501" />
            </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.youtubeLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-youtube h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-green lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <rect x="3" y="5" width="18" height="14" rx="4" />
                <path d="M10 9l5 3l-5 3z" />
            </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.pinterestLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-pinterest h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white "  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <line x1="8" y1="20" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M10.7 14c.437 1.263 1.43 2 2.55 2c2.071 0 3.75 -1.554 3.75 -4a5 5 0 1 0 -9.7 1.7" />
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            </div>

            </div>
            {/* The Navbar First section Ends */}

            {/* The dropdown starts */}

            { dropdown &&



            < motion.div

            initial={{ scale: 0 }}
            animate={{ scale: 1}}
            // transition={{ type: "spring", bounce: 0.25 }}

            className="absolute overflow-auto w-3/4 xl:w-1/4 pl-3 z-50 space-y-4 max-h-screen left-0 mt-0 top-0 m-auto rounded-sm shadow bg-gray-50">

                {/* The dropdow navigational section starts */}
                <div className="flex justify-end items-center px-2 py-3">


                <svg onClick={closeDropdown} className="w-6 h-6 rounded-full py-1 px-1 hover:bg-ragan-green hover:text-white" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" /></svg>


                </div>
                {/* The drop down navigation section ends */}

                {/* The dropdown body section starts */}

                <div className=" space-y-1">

                <Link to="/" className="block font-body tracking-wider px-3 py-3 hover:text-green-600"> Home </Link>

                {

                    accordionData.map((item, index) => {

                        return(
                            

                            <div  className="cursor-pointer block font-body tracking-widest px-3 py-3 hover:text-ragan-green" onClick={() => setsubNav(!subNav)}> {item.title}
                                    {subNav && item.subTitle.map((item, index) =>{

                                    return(

                                    <div className=""> <Link to={item.url} className="block font-body tracking-wider px-3 py-3 text-gray-800 hover:text-ragan-blue"> {item.name} </Link></div>

                                    )

                                    }


                    


                    
                
                            
                            )

                    }

            

                        

                            
                            </div>

                        )       

                    })
                }

                </div>

                {/* The dropdown body section ends */}


                {/* The dropdown footer section Starts */}


                <div className="flex justify-between py-3 px-2 space-x-2 items-center">

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.facebookLink}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-facebook h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <path d="M7 10v4h3v7h4v-7h3l1 -4h-4v-2a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h3v-4h-3a5 5 0 0 0 -5 5v2h-3" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.linkedinLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-linkedin h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="2" />
                <line x1="8" y1="11" x2="8" y2="16" />
                <line x1="8" y1="8" x2="8" y2="8.01" />
                <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M16 16v-3a2 2 0 0 0 -4 0" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.instagramLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-instagram h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="4" />
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3" />
            <line x1="16.5" y1="7.5" x2="16.5" y2="7.501" />
            </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.youtubeLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-youtube h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <rect x="3" y="5" width="18" height="14" rx="4" />
                <path d="M10 9l5 3l-5 3z" />
            </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.pinterestLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-pinterest h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white "  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <line x1="8" y1="20" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M10.7 14c.437 1.263 1.43 2 2.55 2c2.071 0 3.75 -1.554 3.75 -4a5 5 0 1 0 -9.7 1.7" />
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            </div>


                {/* The dropdown footer section ends */}





            </motion.div>


            }
            {/* The Dropdown ends */}

        </nav>

        {/* The navigational Bar ends */}
        </>

    )
}

export default Navbar
```

The problem is that anytime  I click the one of the item on the sidebar menu all of the  submenu Item just drops down as shown below

[image: React component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, The Problem here is you are using a boolean value (`subNav`) to hide/show the `submenu`.  if `subNav` is true then all the `submenu's` will be shown and vice versa.
Instead of `boolean` you can use an `integer` which represents the index of the `main menu item`. if the index of the main menu item equals to the state (`subNav`) then will show the submenu otherwise will hide it.

```
const [subNav, setsubNav] = useState(-1); // -1 is the initial value becoz we need to hide all the submenu's initially.

{
   accordionData.map((item, index) => {
      return(
         <div className="cursor-pointer block font-body tracking-widest px-3 py-3 hover:text-ragan-green" onClick={() => setsubNav(index)}> {item.title}
            {subNav === index && item.subTitle.map((item, subIndex) =>{
               return(
                  <div className=""> <Link to={item.url} className="block font-body tracking-wider px-3 py-3 text-gray-800 hover:text-ragan-blue"> {item.name} </Link></div>
               )
             })
             }
         </div>
       )       
     })
}
```

`suNav === index` is the condition to check the selected menu.

Comment: I got errors, something went wrong with the subindex

Comment: The sub nav did not open

Comment: where are you using the `toggle` function? , and inside that function put `return setsubNav(-1)` instead of `return setsubNav(null)`

and put `index` instead of `subIndex` in `accordionData.map((item, index) => {})`

Comment: I am not using the toggle function, Instead, I am using the setSubnav Function directly

Answer (score 0):

so Here is the final code that actually worked.

```
import  * as React  from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
import {Link} from "gatsby"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

import accordionData from "./accordiondata"


import { motion } from "framer-motion"


const Navbar  = () =>{

    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
            datoCmsGlobalContent {
                facebookLink
                linkedinLink
                instagramLink
                pinterestLink
                youtubeLink
                mainSiteLogo {
                    gatsbyImageData
                    alt
                }
                apptRequestCopy
                apptRequestLink
                telephoneNumber
                telephoneLink
            }
        }
    `)



    const [dropdown, setdropdown] = useState(false)

    const [subNav, setsubNav] = useState(-1);

    const toggle = index =>{

        if (setsubNav === index){

            return setsubNav(null)
        }

        setsubNav(index)
    }

    const openDropdown  = () =>{

        setdropdown(true)

    }

    const closeDropdown  = () =>{

        setdropdown(false)

    }



    return(
        <>
        {/* The top navigational bar to show on mobile starts */}
        <div className="flex justify-center py-2 md:hidden ">
            <Link to="/">
                <GatsbyImage
                    image={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.mainSiteLogo.gatsbyImageData}
                    className="h-auto w-auto object-cover object-center"
                    alt="{data.datoCmsGlobalContent.mainSiteLogo.alt}"
                />
            </Link>
        </div>
        {/* The top navigational bar to show on mobile Ends */}

        {/* The navigational bar starts */}
        <nav className="relative flex justify-between py-2 px-6 bg-white text-gray-800 shadow-sm items-center tracking-wider sticky top-0 z-50">

            {/* The Navbar first flex section Starts*/}
            <div className="flex justify-between space-x-8 items-center">

                <button onClick={openDropdown} className="bg-ragan-purple flex p-3 rounded-md overflow-hidden space-x-4 items-center focus:outline-none">
                    <svg className="w-6 h-6 text-white" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                    </svg>
                    <span className="tracking-wider font-body text-white">MENU</span>
                </button>

                <Link to={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.apptRequestLink} >
                    <button className="bg-ragan-orange text-white  p-3 tracking-wider font-body rounded-md focus:outline-none hidden xl:block">
                        {data.datoCmsGlobalContent.apptRequestCopy}
                    </button>
                </Link>

            </div>
            {/* The Navbar First section Ends */}

            {/* The Navbar Second section Starts */}
            <div className="hidden lg:block">
                <Link to="/">
                    <GatsbyImage
                        image={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.mainSiteLogo.gatsbyImageData}
                        className="h-auto w-auto object-cover object-center"
                        alt="{data.datoCmsGlobalContent.mainSiteLogo.alt}"
                    />
                </Link>
            </div>
            {/* The Navbar Second section Ends */}

            {/* The Navbar first flex section Starts*/}
            <div className="flex justify-between space-x-8 items-center">

                <div>

                <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.telephoneLink}>
                <button className="bg-ragan-blue text-white py-3 px-3 tracking-wider font-body rounded-md focus:outline-none hidden xl:block">
                {data.datoCmsGlobalContent.telephoneNumber}
                </button>
                </a>

                </div>


                <div className="flex justify-between space-x-2 items-center">

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.facebookLink}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-facebook h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <path d="M7 10v4h3v7h4v-7h3l1 -4h-4v-2a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h3v-4h-3a5 5 0 0 0 -5 5v2h-3" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.linkedinLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-linkedin h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-green lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="2" />
                <line x1="8" y1="11" x2="8" y2="16" />
                <line x1="8" y1="8" x2="8" y2="8.01" />
                <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M16 16v-3a2 2 0 0 0 -4 0" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.instagramLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-instagram h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="4" />
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3" />
            <line x1="16.5" y1="7.5" x2="16.5" y2="7.501" />
            </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.youtubeLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-youtube h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-green lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <rect x="3" y="5" width="18" height="14" rx="4" />
                <path d="M10 9l5 3l-5 3z" />
            </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.pinterestLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-pinterest h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white "  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <line x1="8" y1="20" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M10.7 14c.437 1.263 1.43 2 2.55 2c2.071 0 3.75 -1.554 3.75 -4a5 5 0 1 0 -9.7 1.7" />
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            </div>

            </div>
            {/* The Navbar First section Ends */}

            {/* The dropdown starts */}

            { dropdown &&



            < motion.div

            initial={{ scale: 0 }}
            animate={{ scale: 1}}
            // transition={{ type: "spring", bounce: 0.25 }}

            className="absolute overflow-auto w-3/4 xl:w-1/4 pl-3 z-50 space-y-4 max-h-screen left-0 mt-0 top-0 m-auto rounded-sm shadow bg-gray-50">

                {/* The dropdow navigational section starts */}
                <div className="flex justify-end items-center px-2 py-3">


                <svg onClick={closeDropdown} className="w-6 h-6 rounded-full py-1 px-1 hover:bg-ragan-green hover:text-white" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" /></svg>


                </div>
                {/* The drop down navigation section ends */}

                {/* The dropdown body section starts */}

                <div className=" space-y-1">

                <Link to="/" className="block font-body tracking-wider px-3 py-3 hover:text-green-600"> Home </Link>

                {

                    accordionData.map((item, index) => {

                        return(
                            

                            <div  className="cursor-pointer block font-body tracking-widest px-3 py-3 hover:text-ragan-green" onClick={() => toggle(index)}> {item.title}
                                    {subNav === index && item.subTitle.map((item, index) =>{

                                    return(

                                    <div className=""> <Link to={item.url} className="block font-body tracking-wider px-3 py-3 text-gray-800 hover:text-ragan-blue"> {item.name} </Link></div>

                                    )

                                    }


                
                            
                            )

                    }

            

                        

                            
                            </div>

                        )       

                    })
                }

                </div>

                {/* The dropdown body section ends */}


                {/* The dropdown footer section Starts */}


                <div className="flex justify-between py-3 px-2 space-x-2 items-center">

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.facebookLink}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-facebook h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <path d="M7 10v4h3v7h4v-7h3l1 -4h-4v-2a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h3v-4h-3a5 5 0 0 0 -5 5v2h-3" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.linkedinLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-linkedin h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="2" />
                <line x1="8" y1="11" x2="8" y2="16" />
                <line x1="8" y1="8" x2="8" y2="8.01" />
                <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M16 16v-3a2 2 0 0 0 -4 0" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.instagramLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-instagram h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="4" />
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3" />
            <line x1="16.5" y1="7.5" x2="16.5" y2="7.501" />
            </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.youtubeLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-youtube h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <rect x="3" y="5" width="18" height="14" rx="4" />
                <path d="M10 9l5 3l-5 3z" />
            </svg>

            </a>

            <a href={data.datoCmsGlobalContent.pinterestLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-pinterest h-5 w-5 lg:h-12 lg:w-12 lg:rounded-full lg:px-3 lg:py-3 lg:hover:bg-ragan-blue lg:hover:text-white "  viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <line x1="8" y1="20" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M10.7 14c.437 1.263 1.43 2 2.55 2c2.071 0 3.75 -1.554 3.75 -4a5 5 0 1 0 -9.7 1.7" />
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" />
                </svg>

            </a>

            </div>


                {/* The dropdown footer section ends */}





            </motion.div>


            }
            {/* The Dropdown ends */}

        </nav>

        {/* The navigational Bar ends */}
        </>

    )
}

export default Navbar
```